# jquery not working in struts 2.0 jsp page

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am trying to disable a `<s:textfield>`

When I am using the below code its working..

```
document.getElementById("Animal.dog").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
```

But if I am using

```
$("#Animal.dog").attr("disabled", true);
```

its not working..

The struts textfields are created based on the input from the action class.. That is `<s:textfields>` are created dynamically.

The code is:

`<s:textfield name="Animal_%{#eachColumnID}" theme="simple" id="Animal.%{#eachColumnID}" />`

Any idea, why jquery code is not working but only javascript is working.
I am importing jquery lib in jsp page.

Comment: For disabling using `.attr` you should use `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` or use the method Aleksandr suggested

Comment: instead of struts can you plz post the generated markup to lookup what is been added in the html text input. you are using `#` for id don't know if you `styleId` is needed in the struts for generating the html oriented id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

And change your id to use say `-` instead of `.`, because dot is [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

```
$("#Animal-dog").prop("disabled", true);

<s:textfield name="Animal_%{#eachColumnID}" theme="simple" id="Animal-%{#eachColumnID}" />
```

Comment: @abyin007 #Animal.dog makes Jquery look for a element with Id as 'Animal' and class 'dog'. Consider Renaming the id. May be 'Animal_dog'

Comment: thanks a lot friends... when i renamed it.. its working now.. :-)